# searchview with recycler view is not working properly

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

hi  i am developing one app where i have implemented recycler view and searchview in fregement.i get the filter product first time according to text change.
But when i delete text one by one all list will be empty.Notheing can display at the end .

Here is my code from my fragement

Comment: use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85/raw/89a41acded0889028be48e1f669562046cf66126/MatchableRVArrayAdapte%2520(pure%2520RecyclerView%2520style,%2520no%2520implicit%2520TextView%2520mapping)) generic adapter

Answer (score 2):

You are continuously operating on single `array` named `plistarray`

here in `filter()` method you have cleared `plistarray` and again used the same to find the records. so you should use some other array for you adapter rather than `plistarray`

```
public void filter(String text) {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            plistarray.clear();
            plistarray.addAll(plistarray);
        } else {
            ArrayList<ProductList> result = new ArrayList<>();
            text = text.toLowerCase();
            //after clearing the array again you are using same array to find the items from
            for (ProductList item : plistarray) {
                if (item.getPtitle().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                    result.add(item);
                }
            }
             //you have cleared all the contains here
            plistarray.clear();
            // and added only result related items here
            plistarray.addAll(result);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: @unknown apk check my answer and also refer comments in code

Comment: @unknown apk you may accept my answer if that helped you

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the `if (text.isEmpty()) {` block of `filter` method.
Here you clear the `plistarray` list and add that empty list in `plistarray.addAll(plistarray);`

Instead of this add your **original datalist** for the **plistarray.addAll();** This will resolve your empty list problem.
Remember this, when you perform the search always first make a dummy/copy of  original list in constructor of adapter, and use this dummy to restore the data.

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As i see the main problem is you're manipulating the `List` your adapter is populated from, but you do not have a "copy" of the original dataset.

Something like this should work:

```
ArrayList<ProductList> plistarray;     // these are instance variables
ArrayList<ProductList> plistarrayCopy; // in your adapter

// ...

public void filter(String text) {
    if (plistarrayCopy == null) {
        plistarrayCopy = new ArrayList<>(plistarray);
    }

    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        plistarray.clear();
        plistarray.addAll(plistarrayCopy);
        plistarrayCopy = null;
    } else {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<Device> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ProductList pList : plistarrayCopy) {
            if (pList.getPtitle().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                filteredList.add(pList);
            }
        }
        plistarray.clear();
        plistarray.addAll(filteredList);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```